# Adding icon on each array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I created an input element for my array and I wanted to add an icon after each array.
Sample Code:

```
for (i = 0; i < Array.length; i++){
    var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
    input.setAttribute("type", "text");
    input.setAttribute("class","item-choie")
    input.setAttribute("value", Array[i]);
    $('#menu-item').after('<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>');
    document.getElementById('menu-list').appendChild(input); 
}
```

Expected Output:

[image: Output]

Input

->(icon)

Edited: *Thanks for the note of id must be unique*

Comment: `input.setAttribute("id", "menu-item");` in a HTML document, id's MUST be unique - or strange things happen

Comment: I can't see the image because of my proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the *innerHTML* property of *menu-list*.

**Please Note:** The attribute *id* must be unique in a document.

```js
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
  input.setAttribute("type", "text");
  input.setAttribute("id", "menu-item" +i);
  input.setAttribute("class","item-choie")
  input.setAttribute("value", i);
  document.getElementById('menu-list').appendChild(input); 
  document.getElementById('menu-list').innerHTML += '<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>';
}
```

```css
.item-choie{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="menu-list"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An element id must be unique on your DOM, else the first one is getted.

You can change the id selector with the `input` element

```
$(input).after('<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change id selector for every input you are appending else the selector will get the first matching instance and add the icon after that.

```js
var Array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
for (i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
  var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
  input.setAttribute("type", "text");
  var s = 'menu-item' + i;
  input.setAttribute("id", s);
  input.setAttribute("class", "item-choie")
  input.setAttribute("value", Array[i]);
var id = '#menu-item' + i;
  $(id).after('<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>');
  document.getElementById('menu-list').appendChild(input);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu-list"></div>
```